# PHP HTML foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

How would I be able to make a table from php using html with a foreach loop?
My goal is to have a table with href tags for each of the sites. It's just that I'm a newbie to php

```
<?php
 $baseConf = ['site' => [abc.com],[abc.org]];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Default Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <!--<a href="<?php //$site; ?>"><?php //$site; ?></a>-->
            <?php
                foreach($site as $value ) {
                    printf $value;
                  }
             ?>
         </table>
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed my code a bit and this is what worked out:

```
$baseConf = array(
        'site' => array("abc.com","abc.org"),
                );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
         <title>Default Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <!--<a href="<?php //$site; ?>"><?php //$site; ?></a>-->
            <?php
              foreach ($baseConf as $value) {
              //echo "$value\n"; 
              print_r($value);
              }
              ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple for loop and you can grab it from SO. Still I am solving it for you.

I assume you have a multidimensional array. Let's simplify it.

```
$baseConf = ['site' => [example.com],[example.org]];


$sites = $baseConf['site']; // we will loop sites now
```

Now Use the html like this

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Links</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($site); $i++){?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $i?></th>
                <td><a href="<?php echo $site[$i]?>"><?php echo $site[$i]?></a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php}?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks this helped a lot actually since my web server has a different layout than the default but the root is the same so i thought i would just put links to the working websites instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple foreach loop to put `<a>` tag with `href`  in table.

```
<table>

<?php
$sites=$baseConf['site'];

foreach($sites as $item) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="<?= $item ?>">
                <?=$item?>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>

</table>
```